# how to publish messages intended for different consumers on same topic of Kafka server?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have multiple consumers(separate microservices) for our topic and the events which we are publishing on the topic is intended for separate micro services or only one consumer at a time?

Can someone suggest what is the best approach to implement this?

eg. I have partition 0 & 1 in my Kafka topic which is being consumed by CG-A and CG-B.
I am publishing something like this
record-1 for CG-A then record-2 for CG-B then again record-3 for CG-A.

How do i make sure that CG-A consumes record-1 from the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Producers and consumers are completely decoupled. Your producer cannot send records "to a consumer".

Consumers always read all records from the topic partitions they've been assigned, regardless of what processes produced into them.

If only certain records are meant for certain consumer groups, then that's processing logic unique to your own applications post-consumption from Kafka. I.e. add conditional statements to filter those events

Comment: ok, thank you! So if i create separate consumer groups for my microservices, all the records will be available for all CG's. If one CG commits a certain record, will that record be available for other CGs?

Comment: Each group tracks unique offsets, therefore uniquely consume Kafka records (records aren't removed from a topic by consuming them). Groups do not share any information